Autofac generic decorator for different interfaces with the same basis
I have an application that is made up of two layers, WebApi and Domain.
The WebApi has controllers that invoke the business logic in the domain through an interface that is called IInteractor.
public interface IInteractor<TRequestModel, TResponseModel>
{
    Task<TResponseModel> Execute(TRequestModel model);
}

The controller action's responsibilities are:

take a web request
convert it to a request model
call the interactor through the interface IInteractor
convert the interactor's response model to a DTO
and return it to the client

Here is an example of such a controller action:
[HttpGet(Name = nameof(GetFoobar))]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetFoobar(
    [FromServices] IInteractor<GetFoobarRequestModel, OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound>> getFoobar,
    [FromQuery] string candidate
)
{
    var requestModel = new GetFoobarRequestModel(candidate);
    var result = await getFoobar.Execute(requestModel);

    return result
        .Match<ActionResult>(
            foobar => Ok(foobar),
            notFound => NotFound());
}

A concrete interactor looks like this:
public class GetFoobarInteractor : IInteractor<GetFoobarRequestModel, OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound>>
{ ... }

The DI registrations for the interactors are done by conventions.
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblyThatContainsInteractors)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IInteractor<,>))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

And there is a decorator for logging that is registered like this:
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(InteractorLoggingDecorator<,>), typeof(IInteractor<,>));

So far, this works pretty well.
But injecting a closed generic interface, e.g. IInteractor<GetFoobarRequestModel, OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound>>, is a bit cumbersome, since it is hard to read.
I would like to have a more lean interface that amplifies the business concern.
This can be achieved by introducing an interface for each interactor.
public interface IGetFoobar : IInteractor<GetFoobarRequestModel, OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound>>;

Then the concrete interactor implements the new leaner interface:
public class GetFoobarInteractor : IGetFoobar
{ ... }

By doing so, the controller action can get rid of the clumsy interface and becomes more clear:
[HttpGet(Name = nameof(GetFoobar))]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetFoobar(
    [FromServices] IGetFoobar getFoobar,
    [FromQuery] string candidate
)
{ ... }

However, there is an issue now.
The InteractorLoggingDecorator is no longer being called.
I think this is because of .AsImplementedInterfaces(), since it registers the concrete interactor for both interfaces

IGetFoobar
IInteractor<GetFoobarRequestModel, OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound>>

and the decorator works only for the second one.
How can I register the InteractorLoggingDecorator for all interfaces by conventions?

I came up with a different approach using source generators.
At design-time, I just create the GetFoobarInteractor that implements the IInteractor interface.
public class GetFoobarInteractor : IInteractor<GetFoobarRequestModel, OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound>>
{ ... }

After hitting CTRL + SHIFT + B a source generator kicks in and generates two things.
First: An interface that is similar to the closed generic interactor interface IInteractor<GetFoobarRequestModel, OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound>>, but without being generic
public interface IGetFoobar
{
    Task<OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound> Execute(GetFoobarRequestModel requestModel);
} 

Second: A proxy class that implements the interface above.
public sealed class GetFoobarInteractorProxy : IGetFoobar
{
    private readonly IInteractor<GetFoobarRequestModel, OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound>>  _interactor;
    
    public GetFoobarInteractorProxy(
            IInteractor<GetFoobarRequestModel, OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound>> interactor)
    {
        _interactor = interactor;
    }
    
    Task<OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound> Execute(GetFoobarRequestModel requestModel) 
    {
        return _interactor.Execute(requestModel);
    }
}  


The concrete GetFoobarInteractor will be injected into the proxy's constructor as IInteractor<GetFoobarRequestModel, OneOf<GetFoobarResponseModel, NotFound>>.
To make this work I have the following DI registration:
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblyThatContainsInteractors)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IInteractor<,>))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

And in order to use the generated IGetFoobar interface I need to add the following code:
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblyThatContainsUseCases)
    .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("InteractorProxy"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Now, I have a lean IGetFoobar interface that can be injceted into the controller action and decorators will always being called.
